# getting error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.ctx.setLineDash is not a function when trying to convert html to pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

Hello so i want to transform my html page to pdf after clicking a button. In this case i have a ternary operation regarding status in the page, if user click the approve button the value become approved therwise the value is reject.

i have a condtion :

```
{val.Status == "Approved" ? 
<div className='textStatusApprove'>
<p>{val.Status}</p>
</div>
:
<>
{val.Status == "Rejected" ?
<div className='textStatusReject'>
<p>{val.Status}</p>
</div>
:
<div></div>
}
 </>
}
```

When im implementing that in the page i get error like this :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.ctx.setLineDash is not a function
    at CanvasRenderer.<anonymous> (canvas-renderer.ts:862:1)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:102:1)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83:1)
    at tslib.es6.js:76:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:72:1)
    at CanvasRenderer.renderDashedDottedBorder (canvas-renderer.ts:789:1)
    at CanvasRenderer.<anonymous> (canvas-renderer.ts:772:1)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:102:1)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83:1)
```

But if im doing it normaly, (error is not showing) :

```
{val.Status.length > 0 ?         
<p>{val.Status}</p>
 :
<div></div>
 }
```

this is the code :

```
const HistoryDetail = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const {id} = useParams();

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    const [ dataList, setDataList ] = useState([]);
    const [ isSubmitted, SetIsSubmitted ] = useState(false);
    const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
    const { formData, setFormData } = useContext(FormData);
    const [ openModal1, setOpenModal1 ] = useState(false);
    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(false);
    const [ show, setShow ] = useState(false);
    const [ showSuccess, setShowSuccess ] = useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    const handleOpenModal1 = () => setOpenModal1(true);
    const handleCloseModal1 = () => setOpenModal1(false);

    const [mailerState, setMailerState] = useState({
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
    });

    function handleStateChange(e) {
      setMailerState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      }));
    };

   
    const handleNotShowSuccess = (event, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'clickaway') {
        return;
      }
      setShowSuccess(false);
    };
      
    const form = useRef();
    const sendEmail = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      emailjs.sendForm('service_lhgexav', 'template_hevhgr8', form.current, 'dz14yQv4S98N8hMyu')
        .then((result) => {
          setShowSuccess(true);
          SetIsSubmitted(true);
          setTimeout(()=> navigate("/home"), 2000);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        });
    };

    const handleNotShow = (event, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'clickaway') {
        return;
      }
      setShow(false);
    };

    const pdfRef = useRef(null);
    const handleDownload = () => {
      const content = pdfRef.current;
      const doc = new jsPDF("p", "px" , "b1");
        doc.html(content,  {
        callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('Document.pdf');
        }
      });
    };

    const userExpire = () => {
      Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login')
      .then((response)=> {
        if(response.data.loggedIn === true) {
          setEmailLog(response.data.email[0].email);
        } else {
          navigate("/");
        }
      });
    };
  
    const getData = () => {
      Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/registration/${id}`).then((response) => {
        setDataList(response.data);
      });
    };

    const updateUserData = (id, CompanyName, Address, PhoneNumber, PresidentName, AccountManagerEmail, AccountManagerPhone,
      PICEmail, PICPhone, EstablishedDate, EmployeeNumber, NumberOfCustomer, Attachments, SKAny, SKValid, NPWPAny, NPWPValid,
      SIUPAny, SIUPValid, TDPAny, TDPValid, DomisiliAny, DomisiliValid, SPKPAny, SPKPValid, AuditAny, AuditValid, TaxAny, TaxValid, BankAny, BankValid ) => {
      Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
        cName           : formData.newCName.length ? formData.newCName : CompanyName , 
        Address         : formData.newAddress.length ? formData.newAddress : Address,
        phoneNumber     : formData.newPhoneNumber.length ? formData.newPhoneNumber : PhoneNumber,
        presidentName   : formData.newPresidentName.length ? formData.newPresidentName : PresidentName,
        managerEmail    : formData.newManagerEmail.length ? formData.newManagerEmail : AccountManagerEmail , 
        managerPhone    : formData.newManagerPhone.length ? formData.newManagerPhone : AccountManagerPhone , 
        picEmail        : formData.newPICEmail.length ? formData.newPICEmail : PICEmail , 
        picPhone        : formData.newPICPhoneNumber.length ? formData.newPICPhoneNumber : PICPhone , 
        date: formData.newDate.length ? formData.newDate : EstablishedDate , 
        employeeNumber  : formData.newEmployeeNumber.length ? formData.newEmployeeNumber : EmployeeNumber , 
        numberOfCustomer: formData.newNumberOfCustomer.length ? formData.newNumberOfCustomer : NumberOfCustomer ,
        myFile          : formData.newMyFile.length ? formData.newMyFile : Attachments ,
        skAny           : formData.newSKAny.length ? formData.newSKAny : SKAny,
        skValid         : formData.newSKValid.length ? formData.newSKValid : SKValid,
        npwpAny         : formData.newNPWPAny.length ? formData.newNPWPAny : NPWPAny,
        npwpValid       : formData.newNPWPValid.length ? formData.newNPWPValid : NPWPValid,
        siupAny         : formData.newSIUPAny.length ? formData.newSIUPAny : SIUPAny,
        siupValid       : formData.newSIUPValid.length ? formData.newSIUPValid : SIUPValid,
        tdpAny          : formData.newTDPAny.length ? formData.newTDPAny : TDPAny,
        tdpValid        : formData.newTDPValid.length ? formData.newTDPValid : TDPValid,
        domisiliAny     : formData.newDomisiliAny.length ? formData.newDomisiliAny : DomisiliAny,
        domisiliValid   : formData.newDomisiliValid.length ? formData.newDomisiliValid : DomisiliValid,
        spkpAny         : formData.newSPKPAny.length ? formData.newSPKPAny : SPKPAny,
        spkpValid       : formData.newSPKPValid.length ? formData.newSPKPValid : SPKPValid,
        auditAny        : formData.newAuditAny.length ? formData.newAuditAny : AuditAny,
        auditValid      : formData.newAuditValid.length ? formData.newAuditValid : AuditValid,
        taxAny          : formData.newTaxAny.length ? formData.newTaxAny : TaxAny,
        taxValid        : formData.newTaxValid.length ? formData.newTaxValid : TaxValid,
        bankAny         : formData.newBankAny.length ? formData.newBankAny : BankAny,
        bankValid       : formData.newBankValid.length ? formData.newBankValid : BankValid,
        id : id
      }).then((response)=> {
        setShow(true);
        setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(false), 1000);
      });
    };

    const updateStatus = (id, Status, e) => {
      Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/updateStatus" , {
        status: e.target.value, 
        id : id
      }).then(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/send", {
          method: "POST",
          headers : {
          "Content-type" : "application/json",
          },
          body : JSON.stringify({mailerState})
        });
        setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(false), 1000);
      });
    };
   
    const updateSubmitted = (id, e) => {
      Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/updateSubmitted" , {
        submitted: e.target.name, 
        id : id
      }).then((response)=> {
        setShowSuccess(true);
        setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(false), 1000);
      });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      userExpire();
      getData();
    }, [])
       
  return (
    <div>
      <Appbar />
      <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Snackbar open={show} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleNotShow}>
        <Alert onClose={handleNotShow} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
         Updating please wait
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <Snackbar open={showSuccess} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleNotShowSuccess}>
        <Alert onClose={handleNotShowSuccess} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
          Email sent succesfully
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      </Stack>
      <div className='btn-container'>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor : " #DFF6FF", color : "black"}} variant="contained" onClick={handleDownload} startIcon={<DownloadIcon />}>Download</Button>
      {dataList.length ?
      <Button style={{marginLeft : "20px", backgroundColor : " #DFF6FF", color : "black"}} variant="contained" onClick={handleOpen} startIcon={<EditIcon />}>Edit</Button>
      :
      <div></div>
      }
      {dataList.map((val, index) => {
        return(
        <>
          {val.Submitted.length ?
            <div></div>
          : 
          <Button style={{marginLeft : "20px", backgroundColor : " #DFF6FF", color : "black"}} variant="contained" onClick={handleOpenModal1} startIcon={<PublishIcon />}>Submit</Button>
          }
        </>
        )})}
      </div>

      <div className='wrapperWrapper'>
        <div ref={pdfRef}>
          <div className='headerMonitoring'>
            <div className='header-item header-item-1'>
              <img src={PTBSI} alt="logo bsi" />
            </div>
            <div className='header-item header-item-2'>
                <h2>PT Berlian Sistem Informasi</h2>
                <br></br>
                <div className='textDetail'>
                <h4>BSI Vendor Registration</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        

        <div className='flexbox-container'>
          <div className='flexbox-item flexbox-item-1'>
            {dataList.map((val, index) => {
            return (
            <div className="leftDiv" key={index}>
              <h2 className='textSupplier'>Supplier Data</h2>
                <div className='textData'>
                  <p>Company Name : {val.CompanyName}</p>
                  <p>Address: {val.Address}</p>
                  <p>Phone Number : {val.PhoneNumber}</p>
                  <p>President Director (Name) : {val.PresidentName}</p>
                  <p>Account Manager (Email / Phone) : {val.AccountManagerEmail} / {val.AccountManagerPhone}</p> 
                  <p>Escalation PIC (Email / Phone) : {val.PICEmail} / {val.PICPhone}</p> 
                  <p>Established Date :   {moment(val.EstablishedDate).format("DD MMMM YYYY")} </p>
                  <p>Main Business : {val.MainBusiness}</p>
                  <p>Employee Number : {val.EmployeeNumber}</p>
                  <p>Number of Customer : {val.NumberOfCustomer}</p>
                  <p>Attachments : {val.Attachments}</p>
                  <p>ID : {val.id}</p>
                </div>
            </div>     
            )})}
          </div>
          
          <div className='flexbox-item flexbox-item-2'>
            <h2 className='textSupplier'>Document </h2>
            <div className="header_fixed">
              <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Document</th>
                  <th>Any / Not</th>        
                  <th>Valid / Invalid</th>  
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {dataList.map((val, index) => {
              return (
              <tbody className="tableBody" key={index}>
                <tr>
                  <td>SK Menhum & Akta Notaris</td>       
                  <td>{val.SKAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.SKValid}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>NPWP</td>       
                  <td>{val.NPWPAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.NPWPValid}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>SIUP</td>       
                  <td>{val.SIUPAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.SIUPValid}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td>TDP</td>       
                  <td>{val.TDPAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.TDPValid}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td>Surat Domisili</td>       
                  <td>{val.DomisiliAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.DomisiliValid}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td>SPKP</td>       
                  <td>{val.SPKPAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.SPKPValid}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td>Latest Financial Report ( Audit )</td>       
                  <td>{val.AuditAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.AuditValid}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td>Tax Report</td>       
                  <td>{val.TaxAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.TaxValid}</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                  <td>Bank Account</td>       
                  <td>{val.BankAny}</td>   
                  <td>{val.BankValid}</td>
                </tr>    
              </tbody>
              )})}
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        {dataList.map((val, index) => {
        return (
        <div>
        <div className='flexbox-container-2'>
          <div className='item-2 flexbox-item-3'>
            <h2 style={{fontFamily : "Manrope"}}>Statement Condition</h2>
            <p style={{textAlign : "justify"}}>
              I who undersign below is the authorized party of the company to perform legal action to represent the company on conducting its business.
              Our company shall not give any gift in any other form to the parties represents PT. Berlian Sistem Informasi on conducting business transaction with our company.
              If on the future it is found that we breach our obligation as stated on point 2 of this letter, we are ready to accept any legal consequences that will be coming.  
            </p>
            <p style={{textAlign : "right"}}>
              Sign And Stamp
            </p>
            <div key={index}>
             {val.Status == "Approved" ? 
              <div className='textStatusApprove'>
               <p>{val.Status}</p>
              </div>
              :
              <>
              {val.Status == "Rejected" ?
              <div className='textStatusReject'>
               <p>{val.Status}</p>
              </div>
              :
              <div></div>
               }
              </>
              }
              <div style={{textAlign : "right"}} key={index}>
                <p>{val.PresidentName}</p>
                <p>President Director</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        )})}    
      </div>
        
      {dataList.map((val, index) => {
          return(
          <>
          {val.Submitted.length <= 0 ? 
          <div></div>
          : 
          <>
          {val.Status.length <= 0  ? 
            <div className='btnStatus'>
              <div className='btnStatus-item-1'>
                <Button style={{backgroundColor : "#367E18", color : "white"}} name="status" value="Approved" variant='contained'  onClick={(e)=> {
                  updateStatus(val.id, val.Status, e)}}>
                  Approve
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Button style={{backgroundColor : "#FF1E00", color : "white"}} name="status" value="Rejected" variant='contained' onClick={(e)=> {
                updateStatus(val.id, val.Status, e)}}>
                Reject
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          :
          <div></div>  
          }
          </>
          }
          </>
      )})}
      </div>

export default HistoryDetail
```

How do i fix this ?

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of jsPDF. Could you try upgrading it to the latest?

Comment: thanks its actually worked in latest version